# Android ViewPager or HorizontalScrollViewer or What else?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

Would you please help me in one question:

What is the way I should choose to implement a horizontal-scroll view component with snap-effect like `ViewPager`, but with multiple views?

(For example, on Google App when you tap on 'screen preview,' there are
screens with different widths, but they all snap to the left side.)

So I need (on width's form factors):

```
[     page1           ][      page 2      ][       page 3     ]

[ smartphone screen ]

[                  Tablet PC screen                                ]
```

I read the article http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html
but I feel that there should be a better way.

So far the only options I see are `ViewPager` and `Horizontal ScrollView` with `ScrollSmoothly` method. (`Gallery` is deprecated.)

While I realize that `ViewPager` handles the 'snap' automatically, I'm looking for a seemingly continuous `View` more like `HorizontalScroll`.

Should I manually implement 'snap' and memory control on inflating visible `View`s for the HorizontalScroll component?

Can you suggest any other components that might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager` takes a `Fragment` for each page. A`Fragment` can consist of several Views. It looks like `ViewPager` will suit your needs.

Comment: But ViewPager will show only one page. And HorizontalScroll able to add any view's in it.

Comment: While made with Fragments in mind, ViewPagers can work with any view. See [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).